# Why does =:= give an error when the variable is not instantiated, but == doesn't?

Tags: prolog, instantiation-error

```
3 == X.
```

would result in the answer 'no', but

```
3 =:= X
```

would result in an error :

```
! Instantiation error in argument 2 of (=:=)/2
! goal:  3=:=_409
```

Why is this happening? Shouldn't both of them behave the same when one is an uninstantiated variable?

Comment: As a beginner, start with `library(clpfd)` rather than simple arithmetics. There, `X #= 3` just holds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`=:=/2` will **evaluate** the expressions and compare the results - so it cannot have any terms that are not fully instantiated.

In other words, `X =:= Y` is similar to `EX is X, EY is Y, EX = EY` - but it will also do implicit casts e.g. `1 =:= 1.0` evaluates to true.